# Ubuntu Desktop as a server. Should I uninstall the GUI? And if, how?

Tags: server, ssh, desktop-environments, webserver, .desktop

I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version as a LAMP server.

Is a big difference between efficiency when the GNOME desktop environment is running?

or it is better that I remove desktop and use only command line?

I found that solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I'm connecting to the server using SSH. Will the Linux work as previously if I remove desktop with those commands? I mean that I don't lose my data and it will reboot and after that I can connect again using SSH

Comment: It should work, you shouldn't lose data, it should reboot and you should be able to SSH. If you're only using SSH, why did you install the desktop environment in the first place? O.o

Comment: I was a beginner and I thought that with desktop will be easier to work ;) Right now I love command line and I do everything by terminal and SSH.  Server is like 30 km from me. What about efficiency? It seems that to my webpage will connect about 1000 users at the same time. My Server is: Intel Core i7-2600K CPU 3.40 GHz 3.70 GHz;  16 GB RAM. If I remove desktop will it help to serve more users?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ramsize and your possibilities. If you are capable to administrate the server completely from a console (even when problem occurs while a ssh connection is not possible), then there is no need to keep any GUI.

If the machine hast quite much ram, the footprint of Xserver staying in the login screen is very small and the cpu consumption is nearly 0%. In that case, there is no need to think about it. It may consume some more electrical power, but I guess that is not a big point. In that case, it may be helpfull to have a GUI some times.

Comment: If I'm connecting using VNC I see instantly desktop. Should I change something to see login screen?